# Implicit diff. of $(xy)^x = e$ giving two different answers

Tags: calculus

Initial question: take $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ of $(xy)^x = e$.

Take $\ln$ of both sides:

$$\ln\left((xy)^x\right) = \ln(e) \implies x\ln(xy) = 1$$

I will call this equation S.

From equation S, you could take $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of both sides and you will get:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-y(1 + \ln(xy))}{x}$$

However, you could also start with equation S and divide both sides by $x$ to get $\ln(xy) = \frac 1x$.  When this equation is differentiated implicity, I get:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-y(1 + (1/x))}{x}$$

Im probably missing something really simple but it is really annoying me that I am getting two different answers.  Help!

Comment: If $(xy)^x=e$, then $\ln(xy)=\frac{1}{x}$, so they are the same.

Comment: As $\pi r8$ showed, taking different routes to find an implicit derivative will usually give formulas that look different but are both true. I often have this problem in my calculus class: different students get different answers but all those answers are correct.

Comment: Ha!, wow thank you πr8 and Rory, I can't believe how fast that was answered, this site is awesome.  Thanks again :)

Comment: I will use MathJax from now on, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There are many forms you can have, but normally if we can reduce to just one variable we do that. Then you can argue if you spot any problem. $x$ and $y$ in your equation are not independent.

So:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-y(1 + \frac{1}{x})}{x}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-e^{\frac{1}{x}}(1 + \frac{1}{x})}{x^2}=\frac{-e^{\frac{1}{x}}(x + 1)}{x^3}$$

The other way

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-y(1 + \ln(xy))}{x}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-e^{\frac{1}{x}}(1 + \ln(x\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x}))}{x^2}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-e^{\frac{1}{x}}(1 + \frac{1}{x}))}{x^2}=\frac{-e^{\frac{1}{x}}(x + 1)}{x^3}$$

So, they are the same.